# SWFObject Autoplay not working

Tags: swfobject, autostart, autoplay

Can someone help me because I have been googling this for hours and I can't seem to make it work.
I want the audio to play automatically when the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("/Player.swf" + "?" + Math.random(), "content", "520", "300", "9", "#f7f8f3");
so.addParam('wmode', 'transparent');
so.addVariable('id', '**dynamic-code**');
so.addParam('autostart','true');
so.write('flash_player');
</script>
```

when he page loads this is the output:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/Player.swf?0.31587677053175867" width="520" height="300" style="undefined" id="content" name="content" bgcolor="#f7f8f3" quality="high" wmode="transparent" autostart="true" flashvars="id=114128" vmode="transparent">
```

This is my first time to ask here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SWFObject only triggers Flash Player's autoplay, which makes the *SWF* autoplay, not content loaded by the SWF. If you want to make the loaded audio auto-play, you'll need to address it via your SWF's ActionScript.

The audio player you're using might have some documentation about triggering autoplay via flashvars, I'd look it up.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
so.addParam('flashvars','&autostart=true&streamer=http://example.com/examplevideo.mp4');
```

Comment: please explain how your answer will help the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
so.addVariable("autoplay","true");
```